# Как правильно организовать проверку формы при помощи JS и AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как правильно организовать проверку формы.

Есть объект с правилами проверки

```
var errorRules = {    // Объект с правилами
        username: { required: true, double: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 30, symbol: /^[a-z0-9]+$/i }, 
        password: { required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 30, symbol: /^[a-z0-9!-:=?*]+$/i }, 
        email: { required: true, double: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 60, symbol: /^[a-z0-9_-]{1,30}@[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i },
        skype: { required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 60, symbol: /^[a-z0-9\.\:_-]{1,30}$/i }                  
    }
```

Под каждое правило написана своя функция с проверкой.
После нажатия Submit, перебирается форма, смотрит какие проверки нужны и вызывает нужные функции.
Дальше выводятся или не выводятся ошибки.

Но проблема с проверкой double (проверка при помощи AJAX на дубль в БД).
Ответ от сервера приходит позднее, нежели все остальные провоерки и поэтому ошибка не выводится.

Как правильно организовать проверку? спасибо

Comment: сделать эту проверку первой и в коллбэке ответа сервера провести все последующие, если надо

Comment: + если уж отправляете данные на сервер для такой валидации, то логичнее было бы проверить сначало все поля без учета проверки на `double`, а потом отправить  всю форму на сервер для контрольной проверки.  А так получается 1 лишняя переброска данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arrFunc = [
  validate1,
  validate2,
  validate3
];

function validate1(cb) {
  // validate action
  cb();
}

function validate2(cb) {
  // emulate async
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      cb();
    },
    1000
  );
}

function validate3(cb) {
    // validate action
    cb();
}

function validateAll(arrFunc) {
  if (arrFunc.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(arrFunc[0].name + ' start');
  arrFunc[0].call(
    this,
    function() {
      console.log(arrFunc[0].name + ' done');
      validateAll(arrFunc.slice(1, arrFunc.length));
  });
}

validateAll(arrFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Одно слово `async` а столько горя. Вся проблема что запрос асинхронный и все остальное выполняется в независимости от самого запроса, т.е параллельно.

В отправке запроса надо проставить `async: false` наглядный пример я выложил ниже, пока запрос не завершится то последняя проверка не начнется.

```js
    function validate_first() {
        console.log('validate first => true');

        return true;
    }

    function validate_last() {
        console.log('validate last => true');

        return true;
    }

    function validate_second() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=3000 ',
            async: false,
            success: function (answer) {
                console.log('validate second => true');
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    function validate() {
        validate_first();
        validate_second();
        validate_last();

        console.log('success validate')
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
            validate();
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>test</button>
```

Comment: Только вот синхронные запросы давным-давно устарели и планируются к удалению из стандартов и из браузеров, не надо их советовать

Comment: @andreymal честно говоря я почти никогда не пользовался синхронными запросами. можете дать ссылку на статью о удалении со стандартов синхронных запросов, не могу найти в гугле.

Comment: Запустите свой пример, нажмите свою кнопку test и откройте js-консоль в браузере — там будет ссылка